# Switch between databases in PGAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

How we can connect to specific database by using sql commands in pgadmin4 postgresql

in psql command line,its already working \c database name,same thing we want to connect to specific database in pgadmin4 postgresql

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried already.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am creating the database and schema by using below commands by using ide, but schema is creating under postgres(which i was used for authentication) db instead of created database.

1. create user username with password log
2. create database dbname owner username
3. SET SEARCH_PATH TO dbname
4. create schema schemaname AUTHORIZATION username;

But i want schema to be created under newly created database

Comment: You should use `psql`, not pgAdmin, if you want to run a script.

Comment: Actually from our development tool we are trying to create database and schema by using above commands,but schema is not creating under created database

Answer (score 1):

The pgadmin4 SQL window executes only SQL commands, which are bound to a specific database. \c is an internal psql command.
You need to open separate SQL windows per database in pgadmin4.